# What's wrong with this 'fx' expression in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to get rid of the backgrounds on a bunch of images using ImageMagick.  The ImageMagick website documents a [variety of techniques](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove) for doing this. They have also conveniently written a shell script, [bg_removal.sh](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/bg_removal), which contains their preferred combination of these methods.

I'm getting an error in the script though.  When you call the script you give a couple of fuzziness parameters, plus the specific background color if you know it.  Passing an explicit background color, like `RGB(37,188,111)`, results in this fragment of the final command:

```
( +clone -sparse-color voronoi 0,0,RGB(37,188,111) )
```

..and it works fine.  If you don't pass a bgcolor, though, the expression looks like this:

```
( +clone -sparse-color voronoi 0,0,%[fx:p{0,0}] )
```

and it fails with a message about having wrong number of arguments for `-sparse-color`.  I can change it to a different function, and it works:

```
( +clone -sparse-color voronoi 0,0,%[pixel:p{0,0}] )
```

I don't know enough about ImageMagick to know what the `fx` function is doing and whether `pixel` is a acceptable replacement.  I think it's looking to grab the color at coordinates 0,0 to guess the background color, but not exactly sure.  Is the syntax `0,0,%[fx:p{0,0}]` correct?

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick have you installed?

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.6.8-1 2012-05-20 Q16 -- I'll check out your advice below, thanks

Answer (score 4):

`-fx` is an operator that lets you use a mathematical or IM-specific expression to apply to pixels: `-fx 'expression'`.

It was only in ImageMagick version 6.2.10 and later that it was introduced you could use an *escape sequence* like '%[fx:...]' within [image properties escaped strings](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php), for the special occasions *when they are enclosed in braces*. So both these methods should work after v6.2.10:

```
%[fx:expression]
%[pixel:expression]
```

so as to your question: yes, *'pixel **IS** an acceptable replacement'* for fx.

And the expression `p{0,0}` means: *'return the color values for the upper left pixel in the current image'*.

So check your version of ImageMagick:

```
 convert -version
```

As for why the complete expression fails for you because of *'wrong number of arguments'* for `-sparse-color`:

1. Check if `voronoi` is amongst the supported methods for `-sparse-color`:

   `convert -list sparse-color`

   (I assume it is -- otherwise you'd probably see a different error message.)
2. The general syntax for `-sparse-color` is documented as:

   `-sparse-color method 'x,y color ...'`

   This suggests you should maybe use additional quotes to make sparse-color to recognise the correct number of arguments. How about

   `( +clone -sparse-color voronoi '0,0 %[fx:p{0,0}]' )`

   ??

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the an issue where my fx expressions weren't working either despite using v7+.  I changed my command from `convert` to `magick` and then it started working.  Hope this helps someone else from beating their head against the wall.